# How to add backwards in Python?

Tags: python

I have a number for example 35. Is there a function that does 
`35+34+33.....+1 = 630`
I know there is cumsum but its more for arrays and not solid numbers.

Comment: I'm calling an `x/y problem`.  What is the difference for you in the order of adding?  If all you need is the sum, then a direct computation of the arithmetic sequence is all you need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is not quite a built-in function that does exactly that, but you can combine the `sum` function with a range object.

```
result = sum(range(35, 0, -1))
```

The `-1` in that expression makes the range count backwards, so the `sum` starts with `35`, it continues until it reaches `0` then stops (not including the `0` in the sum, though that does not matter here). Of course, the addition operator is associative and commutative, so the order does not matter theoretically. But this does what you asked, in the order you asked. There are, of course, also other ways to get the same result.

In a comment, you seem to say that you want to use the variable `maxlen` rather than the constant `35`. Then just use

```
result = sum(range(maxlen, 0, -1))
```

Comment: i have a variable maxlen = len(df.columns). How can i incorporate that in your formula.  This gives me 35 in the maxlen variable.

Comment: its just a number returned and i want to take that number and count backwards and sum the total (which will later be used for other purposes such as bonferroni  but for now i just want to know how to get to the sum 630.

Comment: @RnD: I tried my second code line with your variable set to `35` and it does get the result `630`. Is that what you wanted?

Answer (score 6):

With the power of math you can compute it efficiently:

```
result = 35 * (35 + 1) // 2  # 630
```

Comment: `x * (x + 1) // 2` is the generic form